# How to count number of duplicates in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of tuples as shown below:

```
listoftups = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('A','B'), ('C','D')]
```

I want to count the number of duplicates in this list of tuples and want the output as follows:

```
A -> B 2
C -> D 2
E -> F 1
G -> H 1
```

How can I do this in python? I was thinking about using counter but not sure. Thank You.

Comment: why would `G->H` feature in your output given its not a dupe?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Counter`

```
listoftups = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('A','B'), ('C','D')] 
from collections import Counter 
for k, v in Counter(listoftups).most_common():
    print "{} -> {} {}".format(k[0], k[1], v)
```

**Output**

```
A -> B 2
C -> D 2
G -> H 1
E -> F 1
```

Comment: This is good but How can I sort this output by the first string in the  list of tuple? When I use counter it sorts it by most to least.

Comment: huh@HellMan? `sorted(Counter([('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('A','B'), ('C','D')]).items())`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list's count method:

```
listoftups = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('A','B'), ('C','D')] 
tup = listoftups.count(('A', 'B')) # returns 2
```

and to count them all into a dictionary:

```
result = dict()
for tup in set(listoftups):
    result[tup] = listoftups.count(tup)
```

or more succinctly with a dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {tup:listoftups.count(tup) for tup in set(listoftups)}
```

After you would have a dictionary of:

```
result = { ('A', 'B'): 2, ('C', 'D'): 2, ('E','F'): 1, ('G', 'H'): 1}
```

and you can print it the same way that fourtheye does it or:

```
for k, v in result.items():
    print k[0] + "->" + k[1] + " ", v
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(int)
def f(tup):
    result[tup] += 1
map(lambda t: f(t), listoftups)

defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {('G', 'H'): 1, ('A', 'B'): 2, ('C', 'D'): 2, ('E', 'F'): 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, get a list with non-duplicated items using a set. Then iterate through them, and print them in the format desired, using count:

```
listoftups = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('A','B'), ('C','D')] 

listoftups = list(set(listoftups))
for el in listoftups:
    print "{} -> {} {}".format(el[0], el[1], listoftups.count(el))
```

If you want to preserve the order, create the unique values like this:

```
tmp = []
for el in listoftups:
    if el not in tmp:
        tmp.append(el)
```

And then do the for loop i did in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter


tuples = [('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F'), ('G', 'H'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D')]

counted = Counter(tuples).most_common()

s_t = sorted(counted, key=lambda x: x[0][0])

for key, value in s_t:
    print key, value
```

The above code will also sort according to the value of the first string in the tuple.

Console session:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tuples = [('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F'), ('G', 'H'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
>>> counted = Counter(tuples).most_common()
>>> counted
Out[8]: [(('C', 'D'), 4), (('A', 'B'), 2), (('G', 'H'), 1), (('E', 'F'), 1)]
>>> sorted_tuples = sorted(counted, key=lambda x: x[0][0])
>>> sorted_tuples
Out[10]: [(('A', 'B'), 2), (('C', 'D'), 4), (('E', 'F'), 1), (('G', 'H'), 1)]
```

Comment: @1_CR I dunno for sure, but its a habbit of mine.