# Python count lists in list

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
data = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('B','A'), ('D','C')]
```

The order of the first and the second elements does not matter so, for example, ('A', 'B') and ('B','A') are treated as same. The desired result would be:

```
('A','B') 2
('C','D') 2
('E','F') 1
('G','H') 1
```

I tried this (adapted from [How to count number of duplicates in a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872364/how-to-count-number-of-duplicates-in-a-list-of-tuples)):

```
data = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('B','A'), ('D','C')]
from collections import Counter 
for i, j in Counter(data).most_common():
    print i, j
```

The result looks like this:

```
('G', 'H') 1
('B', 'A') 1
('E', 'F') 1
('A', 'B') 1
('D', 'C') 1
('C', 'D') 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Will each tuple always only have two items in it?

Comment: Yes. Two items in each tuple.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41259493/3001761, you could adapt this to work with a Counter. Or just `map(frozenset, data)`.

Comment: Count the number of occurences of letters in each list as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving this is to iterate through each tuple and order them alphabetically using `sorted()`. Therefore `("B", "A")` will become `("A", "B")` etc. Then you can proceed to use the code you wrote before to count the occurences

```
from collections import Counter

data = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('B','A'), ('D','C')]

data = [tuple(sorted(item)) for item in data]  # sorts each tuple alphabetically

for i, j in Counter(data).most_common():
    print(i, j)
```

Or without using list comprehension (and using Python 2.x syntax):

```
from collections import Counter

data = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('B','A'), ('D','C')]

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data[i] = tuple(sorted(data[i]))

for i, j in Counter(data).most_common():
    print i, j
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to count counters of the internal tuples, like this:

```
from collections import Counter
data = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('B','A'), ('D','C')]
data = [Counter(x) for x in data]
print Counter([", ".join(list(x.elements())) for x in data]).most_common()
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you don't want to use Counter

```
data_dict = {}
for d in data:
    temp_d = tuple(sorted(d))
    if temp_d in data_dict:
        data_dict[temp_d] += 1
    else:
        data_dict[temp_d] = 1
```

Output

```
{('A', 'B'): 2, ('C', 'D'): 2, ('E', 'F'): 1, ('G', 'H'): 1}
```

And if you use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(data).map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).value_counts()
```

Output

```
(C, D)    2
(A, B)    2
(G, H)    1
(E, F)    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

`tuple` is not the best type for your use case. Consider using `set` instead.

For example,

```
(1, 2) == (2, 1)    # False
{1, 2} == {2, 1}    # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution without loading `Counter` module:

```
data = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('B','A'), ('D','C')]
counts = {}
for t in data:
    k = tuple(sorted(t))
    counts[k] = counts.get(k, 0) + 1

print(counts)
```

The output:

```
{('C', 'D'): 2, ('G', 'H'): 1, ('E', 'F'): 1, ('A', 'B'): 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with pandas. :)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(pd.Series([('a','b'),('b','a'),('c','d')]).apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(list(x))))).value_counts()

#output
(a, b)    2
(c, d)    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You must sort them before count.

```py
data = [('A', 'B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F'), ('G','H'), ('B','A'), ('D','C')]

def count():
    sorted_data = [tuple(sorted(d)) for d in data]
    for i, j in Counter(sorted_data).most_common():
        print(i, j)
```

Comment: Bad solution that wastes computational time.

Comment: I don't think so. Talking about computational time it's ridicuolus if you don't know what exactly you are looking for. Please look better next time:  Kevin, who asked the question, at the end choosed a solution that is exactly the same as the one I suggested.